# On a conjecture involving multiplicative functions and the integers $1836$ and $137$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, totient-function, divisor-sum, multiplicative-function

We denote the Euler's totient as $\varphi(x)$, the Dedekind psi function as $\psi(x)$ and the sum of divisors function as $\sigma(x)$. Are well-known arithmetic functions, see the corresponding articles from Wikipedia or search these in this website Mathematics Stack Exchange. I would like to get idea about the veracity of the following conjecture (I have some computational evidence of it).

For integers $k> 1$ we denote the composition of functions $f^{k)}(n)=f^{k-1)}(f(n))$ with the definition $f^{1)}(n):=f(n)$.

**Conjecture 1.** *Let* $1\leq y<x$ *be integers such that* $2x=27(y-1)$, and satisfy the equations $$\frac{\psi^{2)}(x)}{\psi^{2)}(y)}=\left(\frac{\varphi^{2)}(x)}{\varphi^{2)}(y)}\right)^3\tag{1}$$
and $$\sigma(x)=k!\tag{2}$$ *for some integer*. *Then* $x=1836$ *and* $y=137$.

**Computational evidence.** The conjecture is true for $1\leq k\leq 10$ and $1\leq y<x\leq 3000$ (I agree that this is poor, but with the means at my disposal I cannot improve this).

> **Question.** Is previous conjecture true? What work can be done about it? **Many thanks.**

I don't know if it is possible to find quickly a counterexample for Conjecture 1. In case that you're able to find quicly counterexample, please can you find a counterexample or provide what work can be done to discuss the veracity of Conjecture 2? (What I evoke is the situation in which you can to find a counterexample and the post in this case could to seem poor because my computational evidence is poor, in this case please consider to  find counterexamples for Conjecture 2 or show some what work can be done to discuss the veracity of Conjecture 2). I hope you forgive me, in fact Conjecture 2 seems very nice.

My attempts make computations and to study cases, with the equations that I've deduce in nexts claims.

**Claim 1.** We've that the following statements are true: a) the equation $2x=27(y-1)$ implies that $y>1$ is an odd integer; b) we've that $27\mid x$ and $x$ can be represented as $x=2^\alpha 3^\beta m$ with $y-1=2^{\alpha+1} 3^{\beta-3} m$ for some integers $\alpha\geq 0$, $\beta\geq 3$ and $m\geq 1$ satisfying $\gcd(2,m)=\gcd(3,m)=1$, and c) the equation $(2^{\alpha+1}-1)(3^{\beta+1}-1)\sigma(m)/2=k!$ holds for some integer $k\geq 1$.

Now we use the notation $p^a||n$ for prime povers $p^a$ dividing an integer $n$ with $p^{a+1}\nmid n$.

**Claim 2.** **Under the additional conditions** that $x$ is even **and** $3^3||x$ (therefore $\beta=3$) we've that the following equations hold $\varphi(x)=2^{\alpha} 3^{\beta-1} \varphi(m)$,$\psi(x)=2^{\alpha+1} 3^{\beta} \psi(m)$,$\psi(y)=\psi(2^{\alpha+1} 3^{\beta-3} m+1)$, $\varphi(y-1)=2^\alpha\varphi(m)$ and $\psi(y-1)=2^{\alpha}\cdot 3 \psi(m)$.

We've the same computational evidence for next conjecture.

**Conjecture 2.** *Let* $1\leq y<x$ *be integers such that* $2x=27(y-1)$ *with* $x+y$ *and* $x-y$ *are both prime numbers, and $x$ satisfying the equation* $$\sigma(x)=k!$$ *for some integer* $k\geq 1$, *then* $x=1836$ *and* $y=137$.

### References:

[1] Was edited an excellent answer for my recent post [*On a conjecture involving multiplicative functions and the integers* $1836$ *and* $136$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4701978/on-a-conjecture-involving-multiplicative-functions-and-the-integers-1836-and) on this Mathematics Stack Exchange.

[2] The sequence [*A245015*](https://oeis.org/A245015) from The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences is related to our problem.

Comment: As curiosities, there are more numerical coincidences for the integers $x=1836$ and $y=137$: these integers satisfy equations as $\varphi^{2)}(x)-\varphi^{2)}(y)=2^k$ and $\varphi^{k)}(x)=1$ both for $k=7$ (with $\varphi^{8)}(137)=1$) or $$2\cdot \frac{\psi^{3)}(x)}{\psi^{3)}(y)}=27\cdot\frac{\varphi^{3)}(x)}{\varphi^{3)}(y)},$$
or $\frac{g(x+y)-g(x-y)}{2}=y$ for $g\in\{\varphi,\operatorname{rad},\psi\}$.

Comment: Conjecture $2$ does not hold : Another solution is $$[x,y]=[1105380, 81881]$$  There are at least $2$ more solutions.

Comment: (1/2) Many thanks @Peter your contributions are excellent. It's sad that Conjecture 2 is false, conjectures are based on hope. I add two additional and simple equations as present/award for you: by Euclidean divison by $8m+1=137$ with $m=17$ one has that $5040$ can be expressed as $5040=2(m+1)(8m+1)+\frac{1}{m}\cdot(6m+6)m$ thus with $(6m+6)m=1836$, therefore we can deduce in particular $5040=\frac{m^2-1}{2}(2m+1)$. Similarly one writes  $5040=\sigma(m)(9\cdot\sigma(m-1)+1)$.

Comment: (2/2) My belief (it's true up to $10^7$) is that *if an integer* $m>1$ *satisfies* this last equation $$5040=\sigma(m)(9\cdot\sigma(m-1)+1),$$ *then* $m=17,$ but I don't know how interpret it. Being $m$ a (Fermat) prime, we've $\sigma(m)=\psi(m)$ (I know the section Comments for A001615 from the OEIS). If do you like @Peter this new conjecture I would like that was yours. Thank you very much, I have always appreciated your contributions.

Comment: The conjecture in the comment need only be checked upto $m=5040$ because for $m>5040$ , the first factor is surely larger than $5040$ (because of $\sigma(m)>m$) and the second factor a positive integer.

Comment: Conjecture $1$ holds for $y\le 10^8$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146211/discussion-between-peter-and-user759001).

Comment: If you consider it, feel free to edit an answer with the computational evidence for Conjecture 1, it is required also about for what values of $k$ the computatios works. Additionally you can to refers your arguments that you can to tell me for Conjecture 1 @Peter

Answer (score 0):

I edit this post with numerical coincidences for the integers related to Conjecture 1 if it can be inspiring/help together the work that I show in the body of the post. I hope that there are no typos. On the other hand I refer that the person in comments (this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704493/on-a-conjecture-involving-multiplicative-functions-and-the-integers-1836-and#comment9958632_4704493)) got counterexamples for Conjecture 2, and this user is invited to post the calculations as an answer.

**Claim.** For $k=7$ the integers $x=1836$ and $y=137$ satisfy

A) the equation $$(\varphi(x)+y)^2+4\sigma(x)=\left(k+\frac{\sigma(x)}{k}\right)^2$$
as a consequence of $\varphi(x)=\frac{\sigma(x)}{k}-(y+k)$, where the square is $(k+\sigma(x)/k)^2=727^2$. Addtionally $\varphi(x)=576$ and $576$ can be expressed as $576=4(y+k)$· Also we have $\sigma(2x)=2\sigma(x)+(k-1)!$ and therefore the equation $$\frac{\sigma(2x)}{2k+1}=\frac{\sigma(k)}{k}$$ holds.

B) we can represent the prime numbers $x+y=x+(k-1)!-\varphi(x)-k$ and $x-y=x+\varphi(x)-(k-1)!+k$
with $y$ expressed as $y=(k-1)!-\varphi(x)-k$, therefore $5y=(k-1)!-5k$. Additionally $4y-1$ and $6y-1$ are also prime numbers, thus we get the following  representations for $7!$ $$5040=2(x+y)+2(4y-1)$$
and
$$5040=2(x-y)+2(6y-1).$$

C) for $m=17$ our integers satisfy $$\psi(x)-2x=2\cdot\frac{x}{m}$$
and $y=1+8m$, thus $\psi(x)-2x=(m-1)\frac{x}{y-1}$ (here as tangential detail $\psi(x)=3888$).

Comment: I forgot $y+k=12^2$ and $k=\frac{m+4}{3}$, and that $m$ and $k$ satisfy $\frac{m-2}{k-2}=3$ because $m=\sqrt{y+k}+5$ and $k=\sqrt{y+k}-5$. And the expression for $y$ as $y=\frac{1}{3}(3m^2-31m+71)$.